# Nativescript location module doesn't perform until real gps apps are also running

Tags: android, performance, gps, nativescript

A [simple gps location app](https://github.com/getsetbro/nativescriptapp), straight from the documentation LocationManager example, doesn't work well when tested on 3 different android phones. Please try for yourself.

Properties like altitude, speed, and direction are not displayed. It performs best if it has data, wifi, and gps. Worse if it has wifi and gps. Worst if it has just gps.

However if an app like [GPS Status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) or Google Maps is also running, then it responds well and is useable. Those other apps are unlocking something that the TNS location module isn't.

I made an issue in the [repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/372).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/location/location.android.ts#L131-L158), the `startLocationMonitoring` method takes up to 3 arguments: `onLocation`, `onError` and `options`, where the [options object can have the `desiredAccuracy` property](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/location/location.android.ts#L135).

[If `desiredAccuracy` is set to `enums.Accuracy.high`](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/location/location.android.ts#L144), it'll set the Android accuracy to [ACCURACY_FINE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#ACCURACY_FINE). Default value is ACCURACY_COARSE, which is consistent with the results you're getting.

So what probably you want to do is:

1 - Import `enums` in your `main-page.js`:

```
var enums = require('ui/enums');
```

2 - Add an object as the third parameter to the startLocationMonitoring call, [here](https://github.com/getsetbro/nativescriptapp/blob/master/app/main-page.js#L30-L31):

```
{
    desiredAccuracy: enums.Accuracy.high
}
```

Nb: This is just from looking at the source code, haven't tested it.

Comment: Looks like it would work to set:
{ desiredAccuracy: 3 }

Comment: Of course. enums.Accuracy.high equals 3. As can be seen in [enums.js](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/ui/enums/enums.ts#L73). But as there's an "enum" available, good practice is to refer to it (e.g. what if that number changes to 4, then you shouldn't need to change your code)